# Oracle DB, Inventory stock amount change from transaction

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I'm working on some functionality for a project utilizing Oracle. 
I have two tables, `Inventory` and `Transaction`, where the `Inventory` table has rows of items, with each having a `ID` and `Count`, like : `ID = 'ProductA' Count = 12`

The `Transaction` table has rows of tranasactions, having an `TXID`, `ItemID`, `ItemQuantity`, like : `TXID = '00012', ItemID = 'ProductA', ItemQuantity = 5`

I need to be able to update the item count in `Inventory` when a new transaction is made.

I could do this with multiple statements,

```
INSERT INTO "TRANSACTION"
(TRANSACTIONID ....
VALUES('00012' .....`

UPDATE INVENTORY
SET  Count = Count - ItemQuantity
WHERE ROWID='ProductA'
```

`

But this doesn't seem correct, what if there is some error and not all statements execute.

What kind of format should I be using for this type of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds very much like you want to use SQL ["transactions"](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm).

For example:

```
-- In Oracle, this begins an implicit transaction
INSERT INTO "TRANSACTION"(TRANSACTIONID ....) VALUES('00012 .....)
UPDATE INVENTORY SET  Count = Count - ItemQuantity WHERE ROWID='ProductA'
COMMIT
```

For this to work, you'll need "ItemQuantity" as some kind of variable. I imagine you're reading it from PHP: you can start off using the PHP variable.

Even better, consider using [Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/apis-php-en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.html) and/or [Stored Procedures](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_programs.htm).

You might also consider configuring "TRANSACTIONID" as an [Identity Column](http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-identity-column/).

Additional information:

> - [Oracle Help Center: Transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT89320)
>
> A transaction is a logical, atomic unit of work that contains one or
>   more SQL statements.
>
> A transaction groups SQL statements so that they are either all
>   committed, which means they are applied to the database, or all rolled
>   back, which means they are undone from the database. Oracle Database
>   assigns every transaction a unique identifier called a transaction ID.
>
> All Oracle transactions obey the basic properties of a database
>   transaction, known as ACID properties
>
> - [Oracle Help Center: Managing Transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/api/doc/PC_22/ch08.htm)
>
> A transaction begins with the first executable SQL statement. A
>   transaction ends when it is committed or rolled back, either
>   explicitly with a COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement or implicitly when a
>   DDL statement is issued.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a **trigger after insert** on table `Transaction`, that updates the `Inventory` table.

With this solution, you don't need to execute 2 statements (1 is enough). Also you seamlessly benefit an **atomic transaction**, as, conceptually, changes made within the trigger belong to the same transaction as the operation that fired it.

The way it works :

- Oracle fires the trigger after each successful `INSERT` operation on `Transaction`
- Within the trigger, you have access to the values that were just inserted into `Transaction` using prefix `:NEW` ; you use these values to update `Inventory`

Code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_inventory_after_transaction
AFTER INSERT ON transaction
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE inventory SET Count = Count - :NEW.ItemQuantity WHERE ROWID = :NEW.ID;
END;
/
```

Regarding transaction management, as per [the Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99888) :

> ... if a trigger runs a statement that raises an exception, and the exception is not handled by an exception handler, then the database rolls back the effects of both the trigger and its triggering statement.

Once the trigger is created, following this happen everytime you run an `INSERT` operation on `Transaction` :

- if an error occurs while inserting the transaction, the trigger is not fired
- if the transaction is successfully inserted, the inventory update is fired
- if the trigger fails, the inserted transactions is automatically rolled back
- if everything runs smoothly, then you can safely call `COMMIT`